# HTTP header 'X-Frame-Options' and 'frame-ancestors' directive do not block clickjacking. In Angular-Express js application

Tags: javascript, html, express, iframe, clickjacking

I have an application with a front-end in Angular served by an S3 bucket, and a server in Express js.
To avoid clickjacking I am trying to take all possible actions so: "frame-buster" techniques for the client side and anti-clickjacking header for the server.

For the latter I have tried all the solutions indicated online. That is, I set the "X-Frame-Options" to "DENY" as I do not need any iframes in my application and set the "frame-ancestors" directive with the following code:

```
const app = express();
const helmet = require("helmet");

app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: "DENY" }));
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      frameSrc: ["none"],
      frameAncestors: ["none"],
    },
  })
);
```

I then used this html file to test my application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Iframe test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="inputSite" style="width:400px"/>
<input type="button" value="Open"
onclick="document.getElementById('iframe').src=document.getElementById('inputSite').value"
/>
<br/>
<iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%; height:800px;" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And these are the first http requests sent by the app:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaAOJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I12Rj.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6HTQ.png

Does anyone know what this behaviour is due to and how I can solve it?

Thank you very much, have a nice day